# How to keep the layer control expanded in leaflet? It gets open when the user hover on it by default

Tags: leaflet

```
var baseLayers = {
  "Streets": streets,
  "Grayscale": grayscale,
  "Topography": topograph
};

var overlays = {
  "workplaces": workplaces
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays,myIcon).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I wish people read the documentation more often. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-layers-collapsed

Comment: I tried below example from this site, but it didn't work for me.

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays,null,{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

I also tried to make changes in leaflet.js, but no success.

Comment: Please edit you question and put the actual question in the body of the question.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Its already posted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it. Here is how I answered my question:

`L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays,{

collapsed:false,

}).addTo(map);`